# javascript: how to parse a FileReader object line by line

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript/HTML5 page that I want to use to pull in a file and check each line to see whether it is greater than 240 chars:

EDIT: I have things parsing correctly now, but they're not rendering correctly. Here's my updated code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

    <head>

        <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>
    <body>

    <input type="file" id="input" name="file" multiple />
    <br>
    <output id="files"></output>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>

            if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
                // Great success! All the File APIs are supported.
            } else {
                alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
            }


            function handleFileSelect(evt) {
                var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object


                // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
                var output = [];
                for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

                    var reader = new FileReader();

                    reader.onload = function(e) {
                            // Print the contents of the file
                            var text = e.target.result;

                            var lines = text.split(/[\r\n]+/g); // tolerate both Windows and Unix linebreaks

                            for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                                if (lines[i].length > 240){
                                    output.push('<li>' + lines[i] + '<br>');
                                }
                            }
                    };

                    reader.readAsText(f,"UTF-8");

                }
                document.getElementById('files').innerHTML = 'Paths with more than 240 characters: <br><ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
            }

            document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can run a trace and see that the `output` variable is populating correctly, but all that I'm getting for output is: `Paths with more than 240 characters:` without the `output.join()` part rendering correctly -- any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you should put

```
document.getElementById('files').innerHTML = 'Paths with more than 240 characters: <br><ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
```

inside `onload` callback. Seems that `output` is not yet populated when you try to use it. So:

```
reader.onload = function (e) {
    // all your code ...

    // now can safely print output
    document.getElementById('files').innerHTML = 'Paths with more than 240 characters: <br><ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
};
```

Comment: that did it! I guess it was a local scope issue?

Comment: @fox No. Reading file content is asynchronous operation, so by the time you were trying to use `output` it had not yet been populated.

Answer (score 9):

The obvious way (if you can tolerate reading the file all at once) is to split it by newlines.

```
var lines = text.split(/[\r\n]+/g); // tolerate both Windows and Unix linebreaks
for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) { /* do something with lines[i] */ }
// or in modern JavaScript,
lines.forEach(function(line) { /* ... */ });
```

Comment: why would you want to use the forEach constructor like that?

Comment: It's not a constructor, it's a method on Arrays... Either way, it's just a matter of personal preference.