# Reading txt files line by line in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, file, filereader

So I've been searching for a simply way to read a file and store each string line by line as you go through the file. I know how to do it in Java where you have a file variable and just do file.nextLine() to proceed to the next line till you hit the end.

Was wondering if there is a simple way to just do that. I have a HTML file that has a button with an input tag that grabs a file, but I don't know the syntax to store the file variable in JavaScript and do a loop going line by line and storing each line in different variables.

Thanks for your time and for the help in advance.

```
<button id="list">List All Recipes</button>
<button id="add">Add Recipe</button>
<input id="inputFile" type="file" style="display: none;" />
    <button id="remove">Remove Recipe</button>
    <button id="update">Update Recipe</button>


<script>
    //variable declaration
    var recipeList = [];


    //jQuery for button click event
    $('#add').on('click', function() {
        $('#inputFile').trigger('click');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: read a file? are we talking about Node here or the browser? you are very vague about this.

Comment: my apologize, I want to read a local .txt file. So I can prompt a window to choose a file, then read from it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read FileReader object line-by-line without loading the whole file into RAM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30440709/read-filereader-object-line-by-line-without-loading-the-whole-file-into-ram)

Comment: Well those all seem way to complex. Just a simple read a line in a text file, store it in a string, then read the next line. Nothing more haha.